# Adding routes to url

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, routes

I have some experience in Javascript and just started learning Backbone.js

My URL looks like this:

```
.../index.html
```

and the page looks like this:

[image]

When I click on the `New User` `Button` the URL looks like this:

```
...index.html#/new
```

but I want it to look like this:

```
...index.html/#/new
```

Can someone please explain why my URL doesn't add the extra '`/`' after `.html`

As you'll see in the code below there is a line: `<a href="#/new" class="btn btn-primary">New User</a>`

To try and solve the problem I simply wrote `..."/#/new...` but that didn't work at all.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BackboneTutorials.com Beginner Video</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>User Manager</h1>
        <hr />
        <div class="page"></div>    
    </div>  

<script type="text/template" id="user-list-template">

<a href="#/new" class="btn btn-primary">New User</a>
<hr />
<table class="table striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% _.each(users, function(user) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= user.get('firstname') %></td>
                <td><%= user.get('lastname') %></td>
                <td><%= user.get('age') %></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</table>


</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
        options.url = 'http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com' + options.url;
        });

        var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: '/users'
        });

        var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '.page',
            render: function(){
                var that=this;
                var users = new Users();
                users.fetch({
                    success: function(users){
                        var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html());
                        that.$el.html(template({users: users.models}));
                    }
                })
            }
        });


        var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                '': 'home'
            }
        })

        var userList = new UserList();

        var router = new Router();
        router.on('route:home', function() {
            userList.render();
        });

        Backbone.history.start();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: anybody have any suggestions? I am still stuck on this little issue.

Answer (score 0):

If `.../` opens the same page as `.../index.html` than it will almost do the same as `.../index.html/#/new` it will show `.../#/new` instead. I'm not sure why this is happening but from my experience I know when linking...

- Files don't accept a `/` at the end.
- Directories will read both but it will always end up with an `/` appended.

To make this work you should put some magic into your htaccess file. Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with it.

Comment: hm good tip but still doesn't solve the problem. Hopefully someone knows what to do. Thanks though for your help!

Comment: /index.html/ is not a valid url unless you configured your rewrite rules in your .htaccess to handle that. Anything after the # is exactly that, a hash value. Depending on what browsers you need to support I would recommend turning on the pushState feature for backbone routing.To enable pushState use the following:    Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });

Comment: I tried that but it did not do anything? Anybody have any ideas how I can get the '/' after index.html?